# Component that activates a switch when charged?

Tags: mosfet, switches, relay

this might be super basic but for a geologist it is killing me. I need a low voltage AC device (specifically a dog training collar) to wire to a flashlight so when the remote is pressed the light turns on.

Would a relay (SPST) do this or a MOSFET or??

I have 2 wires off the terminals on the shock collar that output 2V AC at about 2000 uA.

The flashlight has a lead off the batteries to a manual switch. This component needs to replace that manual switch. I am pretty sure every action movie out there uses this scenario .. Lol

Comment: I expect some people here to get upset by the fact you are using the shock collar.. There were precedents.

Comment: Provide a description of how you made the AC voltage and current measurements. What kind of tools? How were those tools applied? (This is a shock collar question and I think we need to be sure of things.) Also, what is the stated purpose of those two terminals that seem to be provided on this shock collar?

Comment: @EugeneSh. in his defence.. he did not say it was on a dog ;D

Comment: Lol. The shock collar is not on a dog. I had one laying around and thought of it being a "free" remote control device. The multimeter indicates the voltage off of the 2 terminals on the shocking device. FWIW a 4KV cattle prod hurts worse 

Answer (score 1):

You can take the AC and peak detect it to turn on a [logic level MOSFET](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDN337N-D.PDF).
Size R1 to adjust the turn on and turn off delay according to the frequency of the signal.

I'm concerned your AC voltage may be a lot higher than your meter is showing you though, so I added a 5.1V zener, D2, to protect the MOSFET.

**HOWEVER :** If the output you are measuring is the shock voltage, it will be in the killo-volts range so don't even think about hooking this up.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvpRqt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Trevor! I am pretty sure it is just in the 2V range since it is coming off a 3V Li-ion battery and it doesn't appear to have capacitors in it. My cattle prod tests at 4KV when depressed. Fortunately my MM has a 4KV MAX ( I noticed AFTER I tested it)

Comment: @BrettH these things usually are simple switched inductors though. The kickback voltage is what gives you the shock, and will be a short but large voltage. Basically the same thing as fires the spark plugs in your car.

Comment: The kick WILL be in the kilovolt range as Trevor says ... probably too short for a multimeter, but unpleasant for dogs, fatal for MOSFETs.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the heads up. So in your proposal the 9V light is isolated from the shock collar current, right?

Comment: @BrettH they need to share a common ground. If you want it isolated things get more complicated and you need a power source on both sides.